# Может ли Postgres 12 выполнять устранение секций в процессе выполнения запроса с подзапросами, возвращающими список значений?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Это исправленная и дополненная в соответствиями с комментариями копия [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111395/can-postgresql-12-do-partition-pruning-at-execution-time-with-subquery-returning), заданного на англоязычном StackOverflow, там я не получил ясного ответа, может быть кто-то в русскоязычном секторе сможет мне помочь.

Я пытаюсь воспользоваться преимуществом партиционирования в одном случае:
У меня есть таблица "events", которая партиционированна по списку (list) по полю "dt_pk", которое ссылается на таблицу "dates".

```sql
-- Schema
drop schema if exists test cascade;
create schema test;

-- Tables
create table if not exists test.dates (
  id bigint primary key,
  dt date   not null
);

create sequence test.seq_events_id;

create table if not exists test.events
(
  id          bigint  not null,
  dt_pk       bigint  not null, 
  content_int bigint,

  foreign key (dt_pk) references test.dates(id) on delete cascade,
  primary key (dt_pk, id)
)
partition by list (dt_pk);

-- Partitions
create table test.events_1 partition of test.events for values in (1);
create table test.events_2 partition of test.events for values in (2);
create table test.events_3 partition of test.events for values in (3);

-- Fill tables
insert into test.dates (id, dt)
select id, dt
from (
  select 1 id, '2020-01-01'::date as dt
union all
  select 2 id, '2020-01-02'::date as dt
union all
  select 3 id, '2020-01-03'::date as dt
) t;

do $$
declare
  dts record;
begin  
  for dts in (
    select id
    from test.dates
  ) loop
    for k in 1..10000 loop    
      insert into test.events (id, dt_pk, content_int)
      values (nextval('test.seq_events_id'), dts.id, random_between(1, 1000000));
    end loop;
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
$$;

vacuum analyze test.dates, test.events;
```

Я хочу получить данные вот по такому запросу:

```sql
select *
from test.events e
  join test.dates d on e.dt_pk = d.id
where d.dt between '2020-01-02'::date and '2020-01-03'::date;
```

Но в этом случае устранение секций не работает. Понятно почему оно не работает, в запросе нет константы на ключ партиционирования. Но из [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/ddl-partitioning#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING) я знаю что существует устранение секций в процессе выполнения запроса, которое должно работать со значениями, полученными из подзапросов.

> Устранение секций может производиться не только при планировании
>   конкретного запроса, но и в процессе его выполнения. Благодаря этому
>   может быть устранено больше секций, когда условные выражения содержат
>   значения, неизвестные во время планирования, например параметры,
>   определённые оператором PREPARE, **значения, получаемые из подзапросов**,
>   или параметризованные значения во внутренней стороне соединения с
>   вложенным циклом.

Тогда я переписал свой запрос таким образом и ожидал получить устранение секций:

```sql
select *
from test.events e
where e.dt_pk in (
  select d.id
  from test.dates d
  where d.dt between '2020-01-02'::date and '2020-01-03'::date
);
```

Но `explain` для этого запроса показывает:

```
Hash Join  (cost=1.07..833.07 rows=20000 width=24) (actual time=3.581..15.989 rows=20000 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (e.dt_pk = d.id)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..642.00 rows=30000 width=24) (actual time=0.005..6.361 rows=30000 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_1 e  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.005..1.104 rows=10000 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_2 e_1  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.005..1.127 rows=10000 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_3 e_2  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.008..1.097 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
        ->  Seq Scan on dates d  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=2 loops=1)
              Filter: ((dt >= '2020-01-02'::date) AND (dt <= '2020-01-03'::date))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.206 ms
Execution Time: 17.237 ms
```

То есть, мы читаем все партиции. Я даже пробовал заставить планировщик использовать соединение вложенными циклами (nested loop join), потому что я прочитал в документации "**параметризованные значения во внутренней стороне соединения с вложенным циклом**", но это не работает:

```sql
set enable_hashjoin to off;
set enable_mergejoin to off;
set enable_material to off;
```

И опять:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2035.05 rows=20000 width=24) (actual time=3.776..25.389 rows=20000 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (e.dt_pk = d.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 40000
  ->  Seq Scan on dates d  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
        Filter: ((dt >= '2020-01-02'::date) AND (dt <= '2020-01-03'::date))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..642.00 rows=30000 width=24) (actual time=0.003..6.412 rows=30000 loops=2)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_1 e  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.002..1.038 rows=10000 loops=2)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_2 e_1  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.004..1.094 rows=10000 loops=2)
        ->  Seq Scan on events_3 e_2  (cost=0.00..164.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.007..1.085 rows=10000 loops=2)
Planning Time: 0.188 ms
Execution Time: 26.680 ms
```

Затем я заметил что во всех примерах "устранения секция во время выполнения" я вижу только условие `=`, но не `in`.
И таким образом это действительно работает:

```sql
explain (analyze) select * from test.events e where e.dt_pk = (select id from test.dates where id = 2);

Append  (cost=1.04..718.04 rows=30000 width=24) (actual time=0.018..3.312 rows=10000 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on dates  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
          Filter: (id = 2)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 2
  ->  Seq Scan on events_1 e  (cost=0.00..189.00 rows=10000 width=24) (never executed)
        Filter: (dt_pk = $0)
  ->  Seq Scan on events_2 e_1  (cost=0.00..189.00 rows=10000 width=24) (actual time=0.005..2.206 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Filter: (dt_pk = $0)
  ->  Seq Scan on events_3 e_2  (cost=0.00..189.00 rows=10000 width=24) (never executed)
        Filter: (dt_pk = $0)
Planning Time: 0.172 ms
Execution Time: 3.978 ms
```

И здесь время для главного вопроса, усечение секций во время выполнения работает только с подзапросами, возвращающими одно значение, или есть какой-то способ получить усечение секций с подзапросом, возвращающим список?

И почему это не работает в случае соединения с вложенными циклами? Может быть я что-то неправильно понял в словах:

> В частности это могут быть значения из подзапросов и значения
>   параметров времени выполнения, например из параметризованных
>   соединений с вложенными циклами.

Или "**параметризованные соединения вложенными циклами**" это не обычные соединения вложенными циклами и есть какое-то отличие?